# Openpyxl ImportError in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04, openpyxl

I've tried everything recommended & still can't get `openpyxl` to work in `Python 3`. I've tried both the `pip3` and `"sudo apt-get install python3-openpyxl"` installation methods & they seem to work fine, but when I open the python3 interpreter & type `"import openpyxl"`, I still get the

> ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'.

It works fine in the python2 interpreter, but I just can't get get it installed for `python3` & need to write my programs in `python3`.

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus` & Python version 3.5.2. I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling the `python3-openpyxl` module but still get the error. Any help out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Mac and using:

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

worked for me.

This works for Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: I have Python 3.8.2 in Windows 7. pip3 install openpyxl solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered this, I will share my eventual work around. I backed up my files & installed Ubuntu 16.10 operating system from a bootable USB. Used Synaptic Package Manager to install openpyxl for Python3 & it is now working.

Not sure this is a bona fide solution, but it worked for my purposes.